# Where can I find audio drivers for a Dell Dimension 3100?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio

I have an older Dell Dimension 3100, and when I put the service tag into Dell's site, it tells me that there are no drivers available for it.  Searching the Dell support site produces similar results.

I had to replace the original hard drive and re-install WinXP, and while I've been able to find drivers for almost everything, the audio won't work.  Windows tries to install "IDT High Definition Audio Codec" but this results in an error.

I've tried searching for drivers, but frankly when it comes to downloading the "drivers" most of the results I found seem pretty sketchy.

Is there a reliable source of drivers where I could find this particular one?

Comment: you have the Dell Dimension 3100 SIGMATEL STAC 92XX HD Audio Driver ?

Comment: When I remove the existing driver, the XP "Add new hardware" wizard tries to install the IDT driver mentioned in the question.  I do not have any other driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's the driver:

ftp://ftp.us.dell.com/audio/R114282.EXE